# Linking LAPACK library with g++ on cygwin

Tags: g++, cygwin, lapack

**Background**

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of a complex matrix by using zgeev routine in LAPACK library. As far as I understand, LAPACK is written for FORTRAN and hence to use it with a C (or C++) program one has to make several modifications such as transforming the matrix and appending an underscore in the routine-name (REFERENCE:http://www.physics.orst.edu/~rubin/nacphy/lapack/codes/eigen-c.html)

**Problem**

To link LAPACK library to a C++ program (http://www.physics.orst.edu/~rubin/nacphy/lapack/codes/eigen-c.html)

and

compile it with g++ on cygwin on my windows 7 laptop, I am using the following command:

```
$ g++ eigen_complex.cpp -L G:\cygwin_root_dir\lib -lliblapack.a -llibblas.a
```

and getiing the following result:

```
eigen_complex.cpp: In function `int main()':
eigen_complex.cpp:41: error: `zgeev_' undeclared (first use this function)
eigen_complex.cpp:41: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
```

I don't understand what is causing this error. Changing the name of the library from liblapack to lapack or to anything (say "lapa") does not make any difference to the error.
The following compiling commands return the same result as above

```
g++ eigen_complex.cpp -L G:\cygwin_root_dir\lib -llapack.a -lblas.a
g++ eigen_complex.cpp -L G:\cygwin_root_dir\lib -llapack -lblas
g++ eigen_complex.cpp -L G:\cygwin_root_dir\lib -lliblapack -llibblas
g++ eigen_complex.cpp -lliblapack -llibblas
```

and

```
g++ eigen_complex.cpp -lliblapack -lxyz
```

also.
I believe there is no library with name xyz  and the compiler is not giving any warning about it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect `zgeev_` is in the library but you are missing a function prototype for it

Comment: Thanks for replying finnw.I added the function prototype.        `void zgeev_(char*, char*,int*,double *, int*, struct complex [], struct complex [1][1], int*, struct complex [1][1], int*, struct complex [], int*, struct complex [], int*);`.  as you suggested but now on compiling with: `g++ eigen_complex.cpp -llapack -lblas`    the error is:  `/tmp/ccOcBaMv.o:eigen_complex.cpp:(.text+0x256): undefined reference to zgeev_(char*, char*, int*, double*, int*, complex*, complex (*) [1], int*, complex (*) [1], int*, complex*, int*, complex*, int*)`
    `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: You also need `extern "C"` in front of the prototype.

Comment: Thanks finnw. It worked :-) Now the program is compiling without any errors.

Comment: Hi @finnw  if you paste your comment as an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: Ok I have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully adding this prototype in a header somewhere in your project should resolve it:

```
extern "C" void zgeev_(char*, char*,int*,double *, int*, struct complex [], struct complex [1][1], int*, struct complex [1][1], int*, struct complex [], int*, struct complex [], int*);
```