# Linking error with LAPACK under cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, lapack

Similar to the problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891423/linking-lapack-library-with-g-on-cygwin), I want to compile a C++ program using LAPACK under Windows 8.1, using cygwin (and written in NetBeans). I got the necessary packages in cygwin (lapack, liblapack-devel, liblapack0), and have written a function prototype:

```
extern "C" void dgeev_(char* jobvl, char* jobvr, int* n, double* a,
    int* lda, double* wr, double* wi, double* vl, int* ldvl,
    double* vr, int* ldvr, double* work, int* lwork, int* info);
```

But trying to compile still throws an error from the linker:

```
$ g++ -llapack -lblas main.cpp 
/tmp/cc3opfN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x349): undefined reference to `dgeev_'
/tmp/cc3opfN5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x403): undefined reference to `dgeev_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code looks like this (adapted from [this example](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/dgeev_ex.c.htm)):

```
/* Locals */
int n = N, lda = LDA, ldvl = LDVL, ldvr = LDVR, info, lwork;
double wkopt;
double* work;
double h = k_max / N;
/* Local arrays */
double wr[N], wi[N], vl[LDVL * N], vr[LDVR * N];
double a[LDA * N];
/* Initialize matrix */
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        a[i * N + j] = integral(i + 1, j + 1);
        if (i == j) {
            a[i * N + j] += diagonal((i + 1) * h);
        }
    }
}
/* Executable statements */
printf(" DGEEV Example Program Results\n");
/* Query and allocate the optimal workspace */
lwork = -1;
char vec[] = "Vectors";
dgeev_(vec, vec, &n, a, &lda, wr, wi, vl, &ldvl, vr, &ldvr,
        &wkopt, &lwork, &info);
lwork = (int) wkopt;
work = (double*) malloc(lwork * sizeof (double));
/* Solve eigenproblem */
dgeev_(vec, vec, &n, a, &lda, wr, wi, vl, &ldvl, vr, &ldvr,
        work, &lwork, &info);
```

What am I missing? :-/

Comment: How does is your `dgeev_` function implementation look like and where (which file) is it located? Also where is the function declaration located?

Comment: Hmm, or is it part of  `LAPACK`? If so, why does it to be declared, instead including its header file?

Comment: It is part of LAPACK. And the function prototype is necessary for the compiler, since LAPACK doesn't have any header files because it is a library (at least I think that is the reason).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that you have installed `BLAS` and `LAPACK` libraries correctly and the system can locate them, then you just have to change the order in the compile command.

```
$ g++ main.cpp -llapack -lblas
```

The compiler should know which functions of `main.cpp` should look into the libraries before declare them.

Comment: I can't believe it, that simple tweak was exactly what I was missing! Thank you!!